# Is it possible to use computer path in Node?

Tags: node.js

Normally in node one would use a path similar to this:

```
../js/hereIsMyJs.js
```

However in mac for example (pc is different)
the path can be `~/Desktop/Ohms/js/hereIsMyJs.js`

Is there any module or way to use the computer path I just presented in node?
I'm using a module that requires the path to where the file should be placed.
It has to work dynamic so the optimal solution would be for me just to feed it the "computer" path.

```
const fileName = '~/Desktop/Ohms/somewhere/here.jpg'
QRCode.toFile(fileName, 'https://example.com')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, it's normal to use node's native path.resolve https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths

```
// Start from current directory, and gives absolute path valid to the current OS.
console.log( path.resolve("../js/hereIsMyJs.js") );  // ie: C:\\projects\\js\\hereIsMyJs.js

// It also accepts multiple arguments, so you can feed it partial paths
path.resolve( "..", "js" ,"hereIsMyJs.js" ); // same result as above.
```

### Other things worth to mention:

- The tilde character `~` is short for the home directory in the *nix world. And works most places not windows.
- In node you can use `require('os').homedir()` to get the home directory
- There is also `__dirname` (gives absolute path of the directory containing the currently executing file) and `process.cwd()` which gives the directory from where you executed your file
- And finally there is `path.join()` which is similar to resolve, but works for joining relative paths, and doesn't care about the current directory.